# Swift: set array as reference

Tags: swift

```
ClassA {
    let arrInt = [1,2,3]
}

ClassB {
    var arrInt: [Int]?

    func init(_ arrIntTmp: [Int]) {
        arrInt = arrIntTmp
    }

    func print() {

    }
}

let classA = ClassA()
let classB = ClassB(classA.arrInt)
classA.arrInt.append(4)
classB.print() // expects to print 1 2 3 4 but up to 3 only
```

I want the array of ClassB to get all the changes done to array in ClassA.
Is array always pass by value?

Comment: You could use `NSMutableArray`. Since it is a class and not a struct, you will get the behavior you want.

Comment: You need to use var not the let

Comment: There are so many errors in this code! Really sloppy question.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks. NSMutableArray did the trick

Answer (score 2):

`Array` and `Dictionary` are *intentially* structs. Their value semantics might seem like a restriction, but it's an intentional design choice to limit unintentional data sharing. When you have an `Array`, you can be *certain* that its content will never change from any kind outside cause. This is really effective at preventing an entire class of tricky bugs, so I would definitely advise you to embrace it.

If you're *certain* that you have no other option, and that you need reference semantics, then you can use the reference counterpart to the struct (E.g. `NS(Mutable)Array` for `Array`). For other structs with no class counterpart, you can use a Box, like I demonstrate below.

```
class Box<T> {
    var contents: T

    init(_ contents: T) {
        self.contents = contents
    }
}


class ClassA {
    var arrInt = Box([1,2,3])
}

class ClassB {
    let arrInt: Box<[Int]>

    init(_ arrInt: Box<[Int]>) {
        self.arrInt = arrInt
    }
}

let objectA = ClassA()
let objectB = ClassB(objectA.arrInt)
objectA.arrInt.contents.append(4)
print(objectB.arrInt.contents)
```